# TensorFlow logs not showing up in Console and File

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, tensorflow

this is probably just a stupid mistake on my end, but I can't seem to find it.

I would like to see the logs from TensorFlow on my console and in the log file, which works for all of my code but the TensorFlow part.

I have configured logging like this:

```
from logging.config import dictConfig
...
# Setup Logging
LOGGING_CONFIG = dict(
    version=1,
    formatters={
        # For files
        'detailed': {'format':
              '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'},
        # For the console
        'console': {'format':
              '[%(levelname)s] %(message)s'}
    },
    handlers={
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'formatter': 'console',
        },
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'formatter': 'detailed',
            'filename': LOG_FILE,
            'mode': 'a',
            'maxBytes': 10485760,  # 10 MB
            'backupCount': 5
        }
    },
    root={
        'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
        'level': logging.DEBUG,
    },
)
dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)
```

I researched this problem and learned that I had to enable logging in TensorFlow with something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
...
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work - the logs are not showing up. If I use `logging.basicConfig()` instead of my own configuration, the logs are displayed as expected. In this case the logs are printed to my terminal.

My conclusion is, that my logging configuration is somewhat faulty - please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [Good logging practice in Python](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/) I found my mistake. The call to `dictConfig` disables existing loggers by default - I had to add a another key to the config to resolve this (`disable_existing_loggers`):

```
# Setup Logging
LOGGING_CONFIG = dict(
    version=1,
    formatters={
        # For files
        'detailed': {'format':
              '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'},
        # For the console
        'console': {'format':
              '[%(levelname)s] %(message)s'}
    },
    handlers={
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'formatter': 'console',
        },
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'formatter': 'detailed',
            'filename': LOG_FILE,
            'mode': 'a',
            'maxBytes': 10485760,  # 10 MB
            'backupCount': 5
        }
    },
    root={
        'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
        'level': logging.DEBUG,
    },
    disable_existing_loggers=False
)
```

Now it works :)